# Quarkus access-log are not displayed

Tags: quarkus

I want access-log in my quarkus application and for this I followed [Documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#quarkus-vertx-http-config-group-access-log-config_configuration).
The problem is, even i have enabled access-log with :

> quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true

No access log found in the console nor in any other file.

Is there any missing in my configuration ? Or should i use any other application server like undertow to be enabled ?

---

Quarkus version : 1.10.3.Final

Project based on quarkus-resteasy extension

content of application.properties

```
quarkus.log.level=WARN
quarkus.log.console.enable=true
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) [%X{X-Request-Id}] [%X{X-Organization-Id}] %s%e%n
quarkus.log.console.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."com.company".level=DEBUG

quarkus.http.access-log.enabled=true
quarkus.http.access-log.pattern=%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b %m "%{i,Referer}" "%{i,User-Agent}" "%{i,X-Request-Id}" "%{i,X-Organization-Id}" %D
quarkus.http.access-log.base-file-name=project-name-log
quarkus.http.access-log.log-directory=/var/log/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing config was :

```
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.http.access-log".level=INFO 
quarkus.http.access-log.log-to-file=true
```